# bootstrap3.0 typeahead plugin not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to get typeahead auto complete work and I don't see it is working.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tK4f6/3/)

```
$('#selectAgent').typeahead({
source: function(query, process) {
    objects = [];
    map = {};
    var data = [{"id":1,"label":"machin"},{"id":2,"label":"truc"}] // Or get your JSON dynamically and load it into this variable
    $.each(data, function(i, object) {
        map[object.label] = object;
        objects.push(object.label);
    });
    process(objects);
},
updater: function(item) {
    $('id').val(map[item].id);
    return item;
}
});
```

//HTML:

```
 <input name="selectAgent" type="text" id="selectAgent" class="validate[required] text-input form-control" data-prompt-position="topLeft:70" placeholder="type &quot;Agent name or id &quot;" title="type &quot;Agent name or id &quot;" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marwan indicated, Typeahead has been dropped from Bootstrap. Your code actually works if you include this library: `http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js` from version 2.3.2.

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sciencepharaoh/tK4f6/5/).

Comment: I am using bootstrap3.0 and twitter.github.io/typeahead.js latest JS file.

Comment: Sorry, I had a console.log in there that will cause it to fail if you don't have a console, updated my link.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Thank you!. I have copied the code to my local workspace and it is not working. Is it conflicting with ny js files? I have jquery 1.10.2, bootstrap.js v3.0.0 and bootstrap-typeahead.js v2.3.2

Comment: If you're going to use the new typeahead.js, you'll need to use the appropriate format for that. You can go here http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ for syntax examples.

Comment: Ihave downloded js file from the uRL you have provided.http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js. It is working fiddle but not in my worspace.

Comment: Aha... Ifound the issue. I have changed your fiddle for onLoad jQuert 1.10.1 instead jQuery1.9.1 and it is not working anymore. I have jQuery 1.10.1 in my workspace so tha tcould be reason. I think bootstrap-typeahead workd only with 1.9.1.